# com.apple.Bluetooth.*.plist in Preferences\ByHost

Tags: macos, settings

I was wondering what is the purpose of the bluetooth .plist file (namely, com.apple.Bluetooth..plist) in Preferences\ByHost. I've accidentally deleted it and it doesn't seem to come back when tinkering with Bluetooth settings (such as deleting known device from the list in Bluetooth settings, or trying to pair with another device).

When the file was present, it used to contain some weird settings like "OBEXBrowseConnectionHandling", "OBEXFTPRootFolderLocation", some sort of MAC Address list called "IDSPairedDevices" which doesn't seem to match with MAC addresses of devices I see in Bluetooth settings in Mac OS interface, but does look like a list of MAC addresses belonging to apple devices. I was wondering where those MAC addresses are from, and what those OBEX settings accomplish.